# Large inputFile becomes null in controller?

Tags: visualforce

I have a visualforce page with an apex:inputFile.  I understand that the limit is 10MB.  But when I upload larger than 10 MB, there's no error.  The controller simply gets null, so I can't tell the user that the file is rejected.  Consider the below simplified code:

**Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="FileErrorTestCtrl" docType="html-5.0" id="pageId" showHeader="false" lightningStylesheets="true" cache="false">
    
    <apex:slds />
    <div class="slds-scope">      
        <apex:form id="formId" enctype="multipart/form-data">           
            <article class="slds-card">
                <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
                    <apex:pagemessages />              
                    
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters">
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12">
                            
                                <div class="slds-col slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters slds-size_12-of-12">
                                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_12-of-12 slds-m-top_medium">
                                        <p class="fieldLabel">Data Upload:</p>
                                        <apex:inputFile value="{!dataFile}" filename="{!dataFileName}" styleclass="" id="fileButton" />   
                                    </div>
                                </div>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 rightpanel">
                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_12-of-12 slds-m-top_medium">
                                    <apex:commandButton styleclass="slds-button slds-button_brand" value="Save"
                                                        action="{!save}"/>                                
                                </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </apex:form>
    </div>
    <script>

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class FileErrorTestCtrl {
    public transient blob dataFile {get;set;}
    public String dataFileName {get;set;}

    
    public FileErrorTestCtrl(){
        //set default values
    }
    
    public PageReference save(){
        String s = 'File size: '+dataFile.size();
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, s));
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

Literally all this does is take a file and output a page message with the file size.  When you upload less than 10 MB, it works fine.  But >10 MB, it gives an error because the dataFile property is null.

The debug log does show a message saying 10MB is the limit.  But how do I catch that error and show it to the user when the controller only gets null?

**EDIT:**

As a side note, here's the Javascript I used to sidestep this issue entirely.  But the accepted answer has the "official" way to catch the server error in the view.

```
<apex:inputFile value="{!dataFile}" filename="{!dataFileName}" styleclass="" id="fileButton" fileSize = "{! fileSize }" onchange="checkFileSize()"/> 

    function checkFileSize() {
        var fileInput = document.getElementById("pageId:formId:fileButton");
        if(fileInput.files.length > 0) {
            var fileSize = fileInput.files[0].size;
            var displaySize = (fileSize / 1048576).toFixed(2) + " MB";
            var allowedSize = 10485760;
            if(fileSize > allowedSize){
                alert('The file size limit for this form is 10MB.  Your file size is ' + displaySize + ' . The file must be sent separately when you are contacted by the team');
                fileInput.value = null;
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand I can use javascript to prevent the file.  But I'm legitimately curious how to return the vf page error to the controller or the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest try to use filesize property of the `apex:inputFile` tag(considering controller approach)  -

```html
<apex:inputFile value="{!dataFile}" 
                fileSize = "{! fileSize }"
                filename="{!dataFileName}" 
                styleclass="" id="fileButton" />
```

Controller will be like -

```java
public Integer fileSize{get;set;}

public PageReference save(){
        if( fileSize >= 10240){
        String s = 'File size: '+ fileSize;
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, s));
        return null;
        }
        else{
          //some handling 
        }
    }
```

Comment: That was the issue!  The platform smacks away any apex:inputFile >10MB.  But if your apex:inputFile doesn't include the fileSize attribute, the platform DOESN'T RETURN THE STANDARD ERROR TO THE VIEW.  It just silently rejects the file and nulls its values.